# Is aggregating outside of Hive a better choice?

Tags: hadoop, hive, db2, hiveql

I have more of a conceptual question. I'm using Hive to pull data and then I want to insert all the retrieved values into IBM BigSQL (basically DB2) so that aggregating data would be easier/faster. So I want to create a view in Hive that I will use nightly perform CTAS so that I can take the table and migrate it to db2 and do the rest of the aggregation. 
Is there a better practice? 
I wanted to do everything including aggregation in Hive but it is extremely slow.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: few questions to clarify. how often will you run your process? what format is your current data? how often change your data? is it only new records or modify existing ones?

Comment: @lake the current process is to run the ETL is every morning for day before. The existing records are not modified. Just read new JSON data format from an on going event stream.

Comment: what distro are you using?  and what kind of aggregations are you doing?

Comment: @lake I'm using Cloudera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are using Cloudera, is there a reason why you don't perform the aggregations in Impala? convert the json data to parquet (I would recommend this if there is not a lot of nested structure) shouldn't be really expensive. Another alternative depending the kind of aggregations that you are doing is use Spark to convert the data (also will depend a lot of your cluster size). I would like to give you more specific hints but without know what aggregations you are doing is be complicated